# Lock screen orientation when targeting Android API 27 with a non-opaque activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have an activity that has `android:windowIsTranslucent` set to `true` and `android:windowBackground` set to a translucent background. I just changed my target and compile sdk version to 27, and I get an exception when launching this activity now:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen opaque activities can request orientation`

Since this is a new sdk, there isn't anything online about it yet (and it seems to result from this line of code: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#987 )

Is there any way to get around this? The app doesn't crash if I take out `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` from my manifest for this activity, but I would like to be able to keep it like that.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to be able to choose the orientation with a translucent activity.  What if the Activity below you doesn't support that activity, or locked it themselves?  How would that work?  If it was ever allowed, it worked on a loophole.

Comment: So my use case is that this translucent activity is only ever displayed in my own app (not as an overlay on another app). It's a Search activity that overlays my main activity, the main activity doesn't rotate either

Comment: After some experimenting, I found that after removing the screenOrientation attribute from similar translucent activities, my activities **still won't rotate**, as the ones **behind them** also have the screenOrientation attribute with the **portrait** value.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I also faced the same problem.
As others said, If I deleted **android:screenOrientation="portrait"** or overrided it with **android:screenOrientation="unspecified"**, then the exception was gone.
And it seems that the front activity's orientation follows the behind activity's orientation.

I thought about it.
If the front activity is transparent and the behind activity's orientation is different,
the display becomes strange.
So, I can understand why this check logic was added
However, I wonder that why this problem was not occurred in Developer Preview 8.0.0.

Comment: I agree with this answer -- however I do question why it only breaks on Oreo as Oreo MR1 is fine.

Comment: had a translucent activity atop our main activity.  both activities were marked `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`.  app would crash if running Android 8.0 with Target API 27.  did not cause a problem when Target API 26, nor API 27 on Android 8.1 or 7.

Comment: I don't have `screenOrientation=` anywhere in my project and this crash still happens.

Comment: @doctorram, maybe you have something like this in your java code `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);`

Comment: @DiogoRosa, yes, I do!

Comment: @doctorram So that's why, that it will make it crash, cause is the same thing as add screenOrientation to manifest

Comment: @doctorram Check my response to this question

Comment: For my application only having landscape. I can't remove in manifest file. Any other solution is there?

Answer (score 16):

The workaround is to set `targetSdk` back to `26`.

The reason why is your application crashes is [here](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/commit/39791594560b2326625b663ed6796882900c220f#diff-960c6fdd4a4b336d98b785268b2a78ff) in this commit.

As you can see [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68454482), you are not the only one - this behavior has been reported to Google as issue. It has been fixed, but we don't know how and when it will be released.

---

I can also confirm what "sofakingforever" says in comments, if there is non-translucent activity with fixed orientation behind your translucent, the translucent will not rotate. So you can just remove `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` from manifest as well.

Comment: This is not a real solution. If someone is targeting API 27, its for a reason.

Comment: @HarishVishwakarma Yes, you are absolutely right. So I have change the word "solution" to "workaround". And it is not forever, because Google will enforce new APK being uploaded to GPlay to target the latest API.

Comment: Presently, the best solution is to change your targetSdk to 26. This is an issue released by google that it will be fixed on new release - Nov 2, 2017 07:47AM 
Marked as Fixed
Our engineering team has fixed this issue. It will be available in a future Android release, so please keep an eye on the release notes.

Comment: @heeleeaz we have Q2 2019, API 29 and still not fixed...  Yes fixed in new Android versions 8.1+ but not in 8.0...

Comment: It is really a "workaround" only. Appreciate for the source of the problem though.

Comment: I dont have real time device to test this scenario I have removed this line `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>` will it help and kept `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`

Answer (score 7):

The solution worked for me is deleting

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

from all the full screen transparent activities which means their theme contains

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

Also to make sure that orientation works correct for below Oreo I added this to the onCreate() of the activities.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // This activity is a fullscreen transparent activity, so after Oreo Android doesn't allow fullscreen
    // transparent activities to specify android:screenOrientation="portrait" in the manifest. It will pick up
    // from the background activity. But for below Oreo we should make sure that requested orientation is portrait.
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT < VERSION_CODES.O) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to lock the activity, since it inherits the orientation from the parent activity, you need to lock the orientation of parent activity. I did it by locking the orientation before the activity starts and release the orientation when the transparent activity finishes. You can do it by starting the activity with a request code and override the onActivityResult(). Check the request code, if that is the request code you are expecting release the orientation.

Answer (score 3):

## I solved this issues by changing this line in NoActionBar styles

> > In target version 27 only i got this issue and i solved by using below line

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
```

Comment: ?? means what @Sakthi

Comment: I used <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item> in style.xml file. But not solved my issue.

Comment: Not getting any error, having design issues. If screen is landscape mode after rotated getting portrait design.

Answer (score 2):

So what I did was remove any screenOrientation property from manifest and add it to my BaseActivity (from which all my activities extend), this code

```
 if(!(this instanceof TranslucentActivity)){
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
```

The TranslucentActivity will have the orientation from the Activity behind.

Comment: The activity needs to be fullscreen too in order to be able to request orientation.  This is very confusing and I really dislike it in Android O.  Instead of crashing which is a big behavior change, they should've simply ignored it (which is also bad!)

Answer (score 1):

it seems like it's a new feature/bug on API 27. 
However, you can delete 
android:screenOrientation 
Or 
android:screenOrientation="unspecified"

Comment: Is is not a bug, the translucent activity acts as a dialog, so it has the same orientation of its parent Activity (the one which started it)

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced the issue and here's the solution.

No need to change the screen orientation parameter which you set at the android manifest file.

Just add two folders in

```
res>values
as  res>values-v26 
and res>values-v27
```

Then copy your styles.xml and themes.xml file there.

and change the following parameters from TRUE to FALSE.

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>

<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
```

It will work.

A common bug of Android 8.0

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @JerabekJakub. My test result - keep sdk 27 and remove the following lines can also solve the crash.

```
 android:configChanges="orientation"
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Comment: reason for removing configChanges??

Comment: But this will cause screen rotation - something that we don't want.

Comment: I have tested mine according to the description of JerabekJakub - if there is non-translucent activity with fixed orientation behind your translucent, the translucent will not rotate.

Comment: Removing android:screenOrientation="portrait" shall be enough

Answer (score 0):

**1) Remove this**

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

from minifiest.xml

**2) on Activity add these two lines**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     setOrientation(this)
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     // other other all code here

 }
```

**3) Just copy-paste the code in your Activity**

```
 public static void setOrientation(Activity context) {
          if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
              context.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
          else
              context.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on Android 8 using `BottomSheetDialog`s. It was crashing every time I open some translucent bottom sheet dialog.

I fixed the problem by adding new `theme.xml` in `values-v26`, with same theme as default one, but completely ***removing*** `windowIsTranslucent` item from there.

After that, I *still* had translucent bottom sheet dialogs in my app and it is working perfectly.

Found it interesting. It may help someone using these dialogs.