# Restrict screen orientation to portrait mode only in Android 8.0 (API level 26) while targeting Android Android 8.1 (API level 27)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, android-orientation, android-8.0-oreo

When I upgraded `compileSdkVersion 26` & `targetSdkVersion 26` to **`compileSdkVersion 27`** & **`targetSdkVersion 27`** in my **build.gradle (Module: app)** file respectively, it works fine with all other android versions but I encounter the following error in Android 8.0 (API level 26) emulator:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: **Only fullscreen opaque
>   activities can request orientation**

Removing `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` worked for me but now my screen is rotating (which I don't want to).

Switching back to `compileSdkVersion 26` again works both ways that is I don't get any error and activity screen is also restricted to portrait only.

But my question is to restrict screen orientation to portrait mode only in Android 8.0 (API level 26) while targeting Android Android 8.1 (API level 27).

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980697/lock-screen-orientation-when-targeting-android-api-27-with-a-non-opaque-activity

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745797/how-to-set-entire-application-in-portrait-mode-only

Comment: i solved it in my project like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48077046/4149649

Comment: Its Worked for me ,If u place the DialogTheme to activity remove the set orientation from the activity tag which is from manifesto , It will take the Orientation from the previous activity

If you don't have that theme no need to remove setorientation from Manifesto..

and for below Versions place this on oncreate

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
  }