# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen opaque activities can request orientation

Tags: java, android, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

I am facing the problem while retrieving the contacts from the contact book in Android 8.0 Oreo java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen opaque activities can request orientation

I am trying to get the contact in my activity from the phone contact book and it works perfect for Lollipop, Marshmallow, Nougat, etc but it will gives me the error for Oreo like this please help me. My code is here below.

**Demo Code :-**

```
private void loadContacts() {
            contactAsync = new ContactLoaderAsync();
            contactAsync.execute();
        }

        private class ContactLoaderAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
            private Cursor numCursor;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                Uri numContacts = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
                String[] numProjection = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE};
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
                    numCursor = InviteByContactActivity.this.managedQuery(numContacts, numProjection, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC");
                } else {
                    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(InviteByContactActivity.this, numContacts, numProjection, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC");
                    numCursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
                }

            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                if (numCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    try {
                        final int contactIdIndex = numCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID);
                        final int displayNameIndex = numCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
                        final int numberIndex = numCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
                        final int typeIndex = numCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE);
                        String displayName, number, type;
                        do {
                            displayName = numCursor.getString(displayNameIndex);
                            number = numCursor.getString(numberIndex);
                            type = getContactTypeString(numCursor.getString(typeIndex), true);
                            final ContactModel contact = new ContactModel(displayName, type, number);
                            phoneNumber = number.replaceAll(" ", "").replaceAll("\\(", "").replaceAll("\\)", "").replaceAll("-", "");

                            if (phoneNumber != null || displayName != null) {
                                contacts.add(phoneNumber);
                                contactsName.add(displayName);
                                contactsChecked.add(false);

                                filterdNames.add(phoneNumber);
                                filterdContactNames.add(displayName);
                                filterdCheckedNames.add(false);
                            }
                        } while (numCursor.moveToNext());
                    } finally {
                        numCursor.close();
                    }
                }


                Collections.sort(contacts, new Comparator<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
                        return lhs.compareToIgnoreCase(rhs);
                    }
                });

                InviteByContactActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mContactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });

                return null;
            }
        }

        private String getContactTypeString(String typeNum, boolean isPhone) {
            String type = PHONE_TYPES.get(typeNum);
            if (type == null)
                return "other";
            return type;
        }

        static HashMap<String, String> PHONE_TYPES = new HashMap<String, String>();

        static {
            PHONE_TYPES.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME + "", "home");
            PHONE_TYPES.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE + "", "mobile");
            PHONE_TYPES.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK + "", "work");
        }
}
```

**Error Log:-**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example, PID: 6573
                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.Activity.InviteByContactActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen opaque activities can request orientation
                                                              Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen opaque activities can request orientation
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745797/how-to-set-entire-application-in-portrait-mode-only

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980697/lock-screen-orientation-when-targeting-android-api-27-with-a-non-opaque-activity

Comment: check this as well :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980697/lock-screen-orientation-when-targeting-android-api-27-with-a-non-opaque-activity

Comment: Tried all suggestion but no one is worked for me.

Comment: are you using  android:screenOrientation="portrait" in manifest?

Comment: yes i have already set it portrait.

Comment: i solved it in my project like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48077046/4149649

Comment: @ShubhamSejpal did you solved? If not, have you extended a NoActionBar theme putting window translucent and are you compiling with `compileSdkVersion =  targetSdkVersion = 27`

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The problem seems to be happening when your target sdk is 28. So after trying out many options finally this worked.

```
<activity
            android:name=".activities.FilterActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Transparent"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
```

style:-

```
<style name="Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
     <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
     <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
     <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
     <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
     <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
     <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
 </style>
```

Note:parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" is needed for api 28. Previously had something else at api 26. Was working great but started to give problem at 28.
Hope it helps someone out here.
EDIT: For some only by setting `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item> and  <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>`
 worked.May be depends upon the way you implement the solution works.In my case it worked by setting them to true.

Comment: To anyone else who stumbles upon this "fix" I had to set `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>` and also had to set `<item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>` before it would work.

Comment: Where exactly is the solution to this? There is no `screenOrientation` attribute in the `activity` tag, and the only thing that causes the crash is `screenOrientation` being set while `android:windowIsTranslucent` is set to true.

Comment: This does not work, unless comments above is used. See answer by Radesh, which covers comments above, and more, and is clear

Comment: Setting translucent to false work for me <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>

Comment: In my case, the solution was to remove 'android:theme' from the Activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
But if you need it, you can add it programmatically before 'super.onCreate':
setTheme(R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog);

Answer (score 209):

In android Oreo (API 26) you can not change orientation for Activity that have below line(s) in style

```
 <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

or

```
 <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
```

You have several way to solving this :

**1)** You can simply remove above line(s) (or turn it to *false*) and your app works fine.

**2)** **Or** you can first **remove** below line from manifest for that activity

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Then you must **add** this line to your activity (in onCreate())

> '>=' change to '!=' thanks to [Entreco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/563904/entreco) comment

```
    //android O fix bug orientation
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT != Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
```

**3)** You can create new `styles.xml` in `values-v26` folder and add this to your `style.xml`. (Thanks to [AbdelHady](https://stackoverflow.com/users/905801/abdelhady) comment)

```
 <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
 <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
```

Comment: on Android PIE this works as expected. So the check really should be: `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT != Build.VERSION_CODES.O`

Comment: @avisper could you please share full condition code

Comment: In a device/emulator running API 26, option 2 doesn't work, I had to make a new `styles.xml` in `values-v26` to disable `android:windowIsTranslucent` for that API only.

Comment: @AbdelHady Good solution, i will add it to my answer but check you code and fine why option 2 doesn't work, that my suggested option,

Comment: I used option 3 with a boolean value `<bool name="allowWindowFullScreenTranslucent">true</bool>` and referred to it in `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">@bool/allowWindowFullScreenTranslucent</item>`.   Then in styles.xml under values-v26 set it to `false` and in values and values-v27 set it to `true`.

Answer (score 96):

In Android O and later this error happens when you set

```
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

in Manifest.

Remove that line and use

```
 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

in your activity.

This will fix your issue.

Comment: Any idea why? I want to restrict my app to go into landscape.

Comment: Its a bug from google side. Should be fixed in future updates. setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); will restrict your app from going into landscape. Make sure you use this in on create of all your activities.

Comment: **Removing** `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>` from my style that inherits from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`  worked for me.

Comment: Then the issue becomes: `Only fullscreen activities can request orientation`. However, I have set the theme of activity to `@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`

Comment: This solution works, but it messes up my splashScreenTheme.  Shame on Google for frequent sloppy roll-outs...

Comment: it does not look like this is a bug but intended : https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/commit/39791594560b2326625b663ed6796882900c220f#diff-960c6fdd4a4b336d98b785268b2a78ff

Comment: "Intended" to break apps that worked on earlier versions? That goal has been definitely achieved. At least we have a solution, thanks to  @Ragesh

Comment: @OlegGryb Took me a long time to figure this out. Glad its of help to fellow developpers

Comment: Many thanks again to @Ragesh. I got a number of crash reports for 8.0 at play console and would never figure it out without his answer. I wish, I could give him more than +1 :)

Comment: Thanks :) I mistakenly placed that `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in my FacebookActivity tag, after removing, it got resolved

Comment: Replacing the manifest attribute by setting the orientation on the Activity class does not solve the problem.

Comment: @rmgoncalo are you using interstitial ads?

Comment: No @RageshRamesh, I have a regular and simple translucent activity. And it crashes on Android 8.0 (fixed on 8.1) either by setting orientation on the manifest or on the Activity's onCreate method

Comment: anyone found the solution

Comment: I'm getting this error with 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1' gradle configuration. I'm updating it to 16.0.1 . I hope it will fix the error. Btw error happens only Android 8.

Also firebase crash gives the following line in the crash report:

'na.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@13280051@13.2.80 (040408-211705629):10)'

Comment: @RageshRamesh, I get this error when I try to set orientation programmatically  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen activities can request orientation

Answer (score 86):

Google throws this exception on Activity's `onCreate` method after v27, their meaning is : if an Activity is translucent or floating, its orientation should be relied on parent(background) Activity, can't make decision on itself.

Even if you remove `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` from the floating or translucent Activity but fix orientation on its parent(background) Activity, it is still fixed by the parent, I have tested already.

One special situation : if you make translucent on a launcher Activity,  it has't parent(background), so always rotate with device. Want to fix it, you have to take another way to replace `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>` style.

Comment: I don't have this issue on my OnePlus running Android PIE. So it's not after v27, but when v!=28

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to the documentation for this ? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: translucent problem is really crazy, thanks ,it fixes my problem

Comment: Thank you for noting that last section 'One special situation...'

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 34):

If you use a fullscreen transparent activity, there is no need to specify the orientation lock on the activity. It will take the configuration settings of the parent activity. So if the parent activity has in the manifest:

> android:screenOrientation="portrait"

your translucent activity will have the same orientation lock: portrait.

Comment: I think you made a small typo: should be "if you use a fullscreen *translucent* activity it will take the configuration setting of its parent activity" ^^

Comment: What if my transparent activity is my launcher activity(i.e. splash screen)

Comment: Is this true for all android versions? Or is it only Android O and upwards?

Comment: This won't work if this is the only Activity that's being used, though (example: starting it from a Service)

Answer (score 33):

I used `android:screenOrientation="behind"` instead of `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`. Basically, you created a dialog (in an activity) and dialog can't request orientation by itself it needs parent activity to do this (because a parent is visible in the background and has own layout).

> "behind"    The same orientation as the activity that's immediately beneath it in the activity stack.

Comment: What if I want the Activity that I've created to be transparent, showing what's beneath it  (including other apps), while also staying on the current orientation?  If I let it stay "behind", it can still change orientation on various cases...

Answer (score 22):

If you have to use `setRequestedOrientation()`, there is no way but sacrifice the windowIsTranslucent attribute on Android 8.0

`values\styles.xml` for api level 25- (<8.0)

```
<style name="Base.Theme.DesignDemo" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        ...
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        ...
    </style>
```

`values-v26\styles.xml` for api level 26 (=8.0)

```
<style name="Base.Theme.DesignDemo" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    ...
    <!-- android 8.0(api26)，Only fullscreen opaque activities can request orientation -->
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
    ...
</style>
```

`values-v27\styles.xml` for api level 27+ (>8.0)

```
<style name="Base.Theme.DesignDemo" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    ...
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Answer (score 21):

The only solution that really works :

Change:

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

to:

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
```

in styles.xml

But this might induce a problem with your splashscreen (white screen at startup)... In this case, add the following line to your styles.xml:

```
 <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
```

just below the windowIsTranslucent line.

Last chance if the previous tips do not work : target SDK 26 instead o 27.

Comment: Changing the target SDK to 26 instead of 27 worked for me.  Changing windowIsTranslucent didn't.

Comment: This worked for me using targetSDK: 27. It is specially important since I had a splashscreen configured.

Answer (score 16):

Many people have given a fix, so I'll talk about the source of the problem.

According to the exception log：

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen opaque activities can request orientation
    at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:1081)
    at android.support.v4.app.SupportActivity.onCreate(SupportActivity.java:66)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:297)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:84)
    at com.nut.blehunter.ui.DialogContainerActivity.onCreate(DialogContainerActivity.java:43)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7372)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3147)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3302) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1891) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
```

The code that triggered the exception in Activity.java

```
    //Need to pay attention mActivityInfo.isFixedOrientation() and ActivityInfo.isTranslucentOrFloating(ta)
    if (getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion >= O_MR1 && mActivityInfo.isFixedOrientation()) {
        final TypedArray ta = obtainStyledAttributes(com.android.internal.R.styleable.Window);
        final boolean isTranslucentOrFloating = ActivityInfo.isTranslucentOrFloating(ta);
        ta.recycle();

        //Exception occurred
        if (isTranslucentOrFloating) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Only fullscreen opaque activities can request orientation");
        }
    }
```

mActivityInfo.isFixedOrientation()：

```
        /**
        * Returns true if the activity's orientation is fixed.
        * @hide
        */
        public boolean isFixedOrientation() {
            return isFixedOrientationLandscape() || isFixedOrientationPortrait()
                    || screenOrientation == SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED;
        }
        /**
        * Returns true if the activity's orientation is fixed to portrait.
        * @hide
        */
        boolean isFixedOrientationPortrait() {
            return isFixedOrientationPortrait(screenOrientation);
        }

        /**
        * Returns true if the activity's orientation is fixed to portrait.
        * @hide
        */
        public static boolean isFixedOrientationPortrait(@ScreenOrientation int orientation) {
            return orientation == SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
                    || orientation == SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT
                    || orientation == SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT
                    || orientation == SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER_PORTRAIT;
        }

        /**
        * Determines whether the {@link Activity} is considered translucent or floating.
        * @hide
        */
        public static boolean isTranslucentOrFloating(TypedArray attributes) {
            final boolean isTranslucent = attributes.getBoolean(com.android.internal.R.styleable.Window_windowIsTranslucent, false);
            final boolean isSwipeToDismiss = !attributes.hasValue(com.android.internal.R.styleable.Window_windowIsTranslucent)
                                            && attributes.getBoolean(com.android.internal.R.styleable.Window_windowSwipeToDismiss, false);
            final boolean isFloating = attributes.getBoolean(com.android.internal.R.styleable.Window_windowIsFloating, false);
            return isFloating || isTranslucent || isSwipeToDismiss;
        }
```

According to the above code analysis, when TargetSdkVersion>=27, when using SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE, SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT, and other related attributes, the use of windowIsTranslucent, windowIsFloating, and windowSwipeToDismiss topic attributes will trigger an exception.

After the problem is found, you can change the TargetSdkVersion or remove the related attributes of the theme according to your needs.

Comment: Checking the code on master at this moment, it's already removed from framework: mirror/platform_frameworks_base/commit/e83f34cde79c51efb66f31f2770c2e8e572e96db#diff-a9aa0352703240c8ae70f1c83add4bc8

It's interesting to see the commit message.

Comment: Can you please show a link to the source code of this part? Is there any workaround that will let me have an Activity with specific orientation AND have a transparent background, so that it will be possible to see what's behind it (including other apps) ?

Answer (score 9):

I can't agree to most rated answer, because

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

causes an error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen opaque activities can
>   request orientation

but this makes it works for me

```
<style name="TranslucentTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

and use it for your Activity, when you extends from

```
InterstitialActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

in AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name=".InterstitialActivity"
        ...
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/TranslucentTheme" />
```

Comment: <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item> => this fixed it for me on android 8.0. I could still leave screenOrientation in the manifest.

Comment: This doesn't work the same as windowIsTranslucent , because now you can't see what's behind the Activity.

Answer (score 9):

Just remove this line `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` of activity in Manifiest.xml

That activity will get orientation from it's previous activity so no need to apply orientation which has `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>`.

Comment: What if the previous activity has a different orientation the what you want in the current activity?

Answer (score 7):

**Just Set Orientation of activity in Manifiest.xml**

```
android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
```

**OR for restricted to Portrait Orientation**

You can also use in Activity, In **`onCreate`** method call before **`super.onCreate(...)`** e.g.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setOrientation(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_xml_layout);
        //...
        //...
}

// Method 
public static void setOrientation(Activity context) {
   if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        context.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
      else
        context.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

it seems when target sdk is pie (api level 28.0) and windowIsTranslucent is true

`<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>`

and you try to access orientation. problem comes with android oreo 8.0 (api level 26) there are two ways to solve this

1. remove the orientation
2. or set windowIsTranslucent to false

if you are setting orientation in manifest like this

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

or 
in activity class like this

```
 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

remove form both places.

and observed when u set  windowIsTranslucent to true, it takes orientation from parent activity.

Answer (score 6):

I recently faced the issue and here's the solution.

No need to change the screen orientation parameter which you set at android manifest file.

Just add two folders in

```
res>values
as  res>values-v26 
and res>values-v27
```

Then copy your styles.xml and themes.xml file there.

and change the following parameters from TRUE to FALSE.

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>

<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
```

It will work.

A common bug of Android 8.0

Answer (score 6):

some of the answers wasnt clear for me and didnt work,

so this was causing the error:

```
<activity
android:name=".ForgotPass_ChangePass"
android:screenOrientation="portrait" <--- // this caused the error
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan|adjustResize"/>
```

android studio was suggeting to set screenOrientation to fullSensor

```
android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
```

yes this will fix the error but i wan to keep my layout in the portrait mode, and fullSensor will act based on the sensor

> "fullSensor"  The orientation is determined by the device orientation
> sensor for any of the 4 orientations. This is similar to "sensor"
> except this allows any of the 4 possible screen orientations,
> regardless of what the device will normally do (for example, some
> devices won't normally use reverse portrait or reverse landscape, but
> this enables those). Added in API level 9.

[source: android:screenOrientation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#screen)

so the solution that worked for me i used "nosensor" :

```
 <activity
        android:name=".ForgotPass_ChangePass"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan|adjustResize"/>
```

> "nosensor"    The orientation is determined without reference to a
> physical orientation sensor. The sensor is ignored, so the display
> will not rotate based on how the user moves the device.

[see android documentation here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#screen)

Answer (score 5):

in the manifest file set second activity parentActivityName as first activity and remove the screenOrientation parameter to the second activity. it means your first activity is the parent and decide to an orientation of your second activity.

```
<activity
        android:name=".view.FirstActiviy"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

<activity
        android:name=".view.SecondActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".view.FirstActiviy"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Transparent" />
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, and my solution was to eliminate the line

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

and then add this in the activity:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

Comment: Please use English on Stack Overflow. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It is a conflict (bug) between Themes inside style.xml file in android versions 7 (Api levels 24,25) & 8 (api levels 26,27),
 when you have

`android:screenOrientation="portrait"`
:inside specific activity (that crashes)  in AndroidManifest.xml

&

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

in the theme that applied to that activity inside style.xml

It can be solve by these ways according to your need :

1- Remove on of the above mentioned properties that make conflict

2- Change Activity orientation to one of these values as you need : `unspecified` or `behind` and so on that can be found here :  [Google reference for android:screenOrientation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#screen)
`

3- Set the orientation programmatically in run time

Comment: Tried this solution, but app still crashes:
I need portrait transparent activity so I need both this options. Tried set in manifest screenOrientation unspecified, but no luck.

Comment: No. I tried remove orientation in manifest at all, and make activity fullscreen, but it still crashes. Only on 1 device - honor 9 lite. On Samsung it works ok.

Comment: Setting the orientation programmatically also causes the crash. How did you use it exactly?

Comment: @androiddeveloper how can I access your source code?!  I must see what you did

Comment: @HamedJaliliani Setting it programmaticaly is as such, for example: ` setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

Comment: @androiddeveloper  what is your  activity tag code in manifest, version of android that you face this error  & logcat error?

Comment: @HamedJaliliani Here's a sample code: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131534974 . Would be easier than to explain in a restricted comment section.

Comment: It's 2023 and we just ran into this! We have
targetSdkVersion 32 and minSdkVersion 26
This solution is closest to what worked for us, we just removed in the manifest
android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
for all activities that were also having
android:windowIsTranslucent
done

Answer (score 3):

After doing some research, it seems that this problem may be due to a google bug.  For me, I was able to leave this line in my Activities onCreate method:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

AND I changed my targetSdkVersion to 26.  Having that line in my onCreate still resulted in a crash while my targetSdkVersion was still set at 27.  Since no one else's solution has worked for me thus far, I found that this works as a temporary fix for now.

Comment: This one worked for me by setting targetSdkVersion to 26, android:screenOrientation="portrait" and <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>

Comment: @siripan for me too

Comment: But eventually you will have to set the targetSdkVersion to 28 this year : https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469#targetsdk . What will you do?

Answer (score 3):

only 8.0.0 throw the exception, above 8.0 has remove the exception

[image: 8.0.0 throw the exception]

Comment: Android 7, 7.1 ,  8.0 , 8.1 all have this problem

Comment: `appInfo.targetSdkVersion > O` throw the exception

Comment: Its checking the `target` sdk version. It doesn't matter what sdk version the device is actually running, you're compiling against Android O (28) but not following the conventions of that version of the platform.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
android:screenOrientation="behind"
```

And Theme

```
<style name="translucent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">#beaaaaaa</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">normal</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustPan</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably you showing Activity looking like Dialog(non-fullscreen), so remove **screenOrientation** from **Manifest** or from code. This will fix the issue.

Comment: Hmm very strange, for me that was the case. Try running the app on different Android versions, see what will be the result this may help you...

Answer (score 2):

I faced this problem only in SDK 26 (8.0.0) if using windowIsTranslucent 'true' and forcefully setting orientation:

Here's the solution:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);   

        // fixing portrait mode problem for SDK 26 if using windowIsTranslucent = true
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 26) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
        } else {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }        
    }



       <style name="SplashActivty" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>



<!-- Splash screen -->
        <activity
            android:name="edu.aku.family_hifazat.activities.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
            android:theme="@style/SplashActivty">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

Comment: But then you lose the functionality of actually having the orientation set to what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error when I try to capture image or take image from gallery what works for me is to remove both

```
 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

and

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

now my activity is using this theme:

```
  <style name="Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, as `windowIsFloating` causes the same crash as `windowIsTranslucent` .

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that worked for me was changing

```xml
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

to

```xml
android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
```

in the manifest for all translucent activities.

That way it is compatible with all API versions since the translucent activity seems to inherit its orientation from the parent activity as of `targetApi: 28`.

The style can be left as it is including `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>`.

Comment: Tried this solution, but app still crashes

Comment: But then you lose the function of setting the orientation

Comment: @androiddeveloper: The way I understand it the orientation will be inherited from the parent activity. If you want to explicitly set another orientation on the translucent activity that wouldn't work this way...

Comment: Sometimes you can't have control of the previous Activity. Sometimes you want to show your transparent one on top of what the user currently sees. So this can't help :(

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue by removing `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` and added below code into my onCreate

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

while my theme properties are

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this is a bug from Google or an intended behavior but I (at least momentarily) solved it by changing compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion back to 26 in Gradle...

Comment: You shouldn't lower the targetsdk level. Your app will be blocked from the play store eventually. Always target the latest Android Api level https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html

Comment: @Shmuel : wrong. You can target 26 and be available on 28 on the store.

Comment: Correct, I wrote 'eventually'  if you build your app targeting an older api level you will be in a world of pain when you are forced to update

Comment: This is not a solution but a workaround. One day you have to migrate your app to 28 and hence!

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't resolved your problem just register the ad activity in the manifest like this:

```
<activity
android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
tools:replace="android:theme"
 />
```

You also need to update to the latest version of the sdk.

Answer (score 1):

this happened after 27,use targetSdkVersion 26 replace, wait for google fixed it

Comment: Please provide any reference (link or quoted) when posting an answer. So future users can understand easily. Also, welcome to the **SO Community**.

Comment: @MohammedsalimShivani Here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68454482#comment4 "Our engineering team has fixed this issue. It will be available in a future Android release, so please keep an eye on the release notes."

Comment: This is bad advice

Answer (score 0):

If the activity created by yourself, you can try this in the Activity:

```
@Override
public void setRequestedOrientation(int requestedOrientation) {
    try {
        super.setRequestedOrientation(requestedOrientation);
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // Only fullscreen activities can request orientation
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This should be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've just removed the tags "portrait" from the non full-screen elements and everything went fine.

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the style of your Activity and make sure if you are not using any Translucent related things, change the style to alternate. So that we can fix this problem.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oreo API 27 transparent and translucent activity can’t request of orientation. Because the previous non opaque activity might have a different orientation as compared to top transparent activity which might create uneven UI behaviour.

opaque activity A (portrait) → transparent activity B (landscape)
If above case was possible we might able to see A portrait from B’s transparent landscape orientation. Which will cut off A’s top and bottom.

A better solution would be to set A’s orientation to portrait if we want B to be portrait. It will inherit the last opaque activity orientation.
Or just make the activity opaque and add your own orientation.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to just avoid the theme itself is to try to set the orientation if possible, all in code:

```
/**tries to set the orientation if possible. Returns true iff succeeded. Not an issue after Android O, because of this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48072438/878126*/
fun requestedOrientationCompat(activity: Activity, requestedOrientation: Int): Boolean {
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT != VERSION_CODES.O) {
        activity.requestedOrientation = requestedOrientation
        return true
    }
    // based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/50809044/878126 https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/d4ecffae67fa0dea03c581ca26f76b87a14be763%5E%21/
    // public static boolean isTranslucentOrFloating(TypedArray attributes) {
    // ...   return isFloating || isTranslucent || isSwipeToDismiss;
    val window = activity.window
    val attributes = window.windowStyle
    //  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable#Window_windowIsTranslucent
    // final boolean isTranslucent = attributes.getBoolean(com.android.internal.R.styleable.Window_windowIsTranslucent, false);
    val styleableWindowIsTranslucent = 5
    val isTranslucent = attributes.getBoolean(styleableWindowIsTranslucent, false)
    // final boolean isSwipeToDismiss = !attributes.hasValue(com.android.internal.R.styleable.Window_windowIsTranslucent)
    //      && attributes.getBoolean(com.android.internal.R.styleable.Window_windowSwipeToDismiss, false);
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    val isSwipeToDismiss =
            !attributes.hasValue(styleableWindowIsTranslucent) && window.hasFeature(Window.FEATURE_SWIPE_TO_DISMISS)
    // https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable#Window_windowIsFloating
    // final boolean isFloating = attributes.getBoolean(com.android.internal.R.styleable.Window_windowIsFloating, false);
    val styleableWindowIsFloating = 4
    val isFloating = attributes.getBoolean(styleableWindowIsFloating, false);
    val isTranslucentOrFloating=isFloating || isTranslucent || isSwipeToDismiss
    if(isTranslucentOrFloating)
        return false
    activity.requestedOrientation = requestedOrientation
    return true
}
```

Alternative for those who prefer extension function:

```
/**tries to set the orientation if possible. Returns true iff succeeded. Not an issue after Android O, because of this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48072438/878126*/
fun Activity.requestedOrientationCompat(requestedOrientation: Int): Boolean{
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT != VERSION_CODES.O) {
        this.requestedOrientation = requestedOrientation
        return true
    }
    // based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/50809044/878126 https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/d4ecffae67fa0dea03c581ca26f76b87a14be763%5E%21/
    // public static boolean isTranslucentOrFloating(TypedArray attributes) {
    // ...   return isFloating || isTranslucent || isSwipeToDismiss;
    val attributes = window.windowStyle
    //  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable#Window_windowIsTranslucent
    // final boolean isTranslucent = attributes.getBoolean(com.android.internal.R.styleable.Window_windowIsTranslucent, false);
    val styleableWindowIsTranslucent = 5
    val isTranslucent = attributes.getBoolean(styleableWindowIsTranslucent, false)
    // final boolean isSwipeToDismiss = !attributes.hasValue(com.android.internal.R.styleable.Window_windowIsTranslucent)
    //      && attributes.getBoolean(com.android.internal.R.styleable.Window_windowSwipeToDismiss, false);
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    val isSwipeToDismiss =
            !attributes.hasValue(styleableWindowIsTranslucent) && window.hasFeature(Window.FEATURE_SWIPE_TO_DISMISS)
    // https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable#Window_windowIsFloating
    // final boolean isFloating = attributes.getBoolean(com.android.internal.R.styleable.Window_windowIsFloating, false);
    val styleableWindowIsFloating = 4
    val isFloating = attributes.getBoolean(styleableWindowIsFloating, false);
    val isTranslucentOrFloating=isFloating || isTranslucent || isSwipeToDismiss
    if(isTranslucentOrFloating)
        return false
    this.requestedOrientation = requestedOrientation
    return true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I fixed it just by setting this: `<item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>` in styles.xml

Answer (score -2):

Try remove lines of your theme:

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

and

```
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
```

after this, add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in your activity.

Answer (score -3):

User extend `AppCompatActivity` & it will work !!