# Application behavior when targetSdkVersion is changed

Tags: android

If the `targetSdkVersion` is greater than the device OS version, and if I lower the `targetSdkVersion` to the device OS version, is the app going to behave differently ?

My application `targetSdkVersion` is 27 and I am running on a `8.0.0[26]` device. I get an `IllegalStateException` as described in the below link, since I am using a dialog `Activity`.

[java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen opaque activities can request orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48072438/java-lang-illegalstateexception-only-fullscreen-opaque-activities-can-request-o)

There were two options suggested. Removing `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` from `AndroidManifest.xml` or changing the `targetSdkVersion` to 26. Both the solutions are working for me.

But my question is regarding changing the `targetSdkVersion` to 26. How is the app behavior going to change when we lower the `targetSdkVersion` from 27 to 26 and the device OS is 26? Since the device is running in 26 and the `targetSdkVersion` is 27, I don't think any compatibility modes are applied. My understanding is, the compatibility mode is applied, when the device OS version is greater than the `targetSdkVersion`.

So how is the app behaviour changing when we change the `targetSdkVersion` here?

Comment: You shouldn't lower the targetsdk level. Your app will be blocked from the play store eventually. Always target the latest Android Api level https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. I ended up using the other option. But just curious to know how lowering targetSdkVersion solves the above issue

Answer (score 0):

Potential yes, your app is going to behave differently. When you set `targetSDKVersion` to 27 your app will be compiled against the API 27 SDKs and linked with the API 27 libraries. If the newer SDK and libraries contain a change that your app code hasn't allowed for then your app could exception. Lowering the `targetSDKVersion` means the app is built against the early SDK and you do not need the code modified for the later SDK changes and thus no exception. However, you lose the ability to use the new features of the later SDK and shorten the time the app stays in the Play store, as older APIs are eventually dropped.

Remember that `targetSDKVersion` has nothing to do with device API support. It is SDK compile version. A `targetSDKVersion` of 26 will run on a device that supports API 27. A `targetSDKVersion` of 27 will run on a 26 API device if you do not use any API 27 features (the workaround is to use the support library versions of the new features, if they have been provided, sometimes new API features do not appear in the support library).

Comment: When targetSDKVersion is 27, I agree it is compiled against the API 27 SDKs. But when it is run in a device with API 26, it should be accessing the API implementations of API 26 right ?  To make it more clearly - the Exception is thrown from the onCreate function. onCreate function of API 27 has the condition check which causes the Exception. But when the built apk runs on API 26 device, which does not have the condition check, which causes the exception, it should not matter if the targetSdkVersion is 27 or 26 right ?

Comment: Also as you pointed out - When you set targetSDKVersion to 27 your app will be compiled against the API 27 SDKs and linked with the API 27 libraries - The API 26 device does not have the 27 SDKs and API libraries right ?

Comment: Yes, an API 27 app on an API 26 device will call the API 26 code even though it is linked to API 27. Due to backwards compatibility, it will not exception unless new API 27 code is called (which is obviously not in an API 26 device, and hence the use of the support library to sometimes provide new API functionality).

Comment: So you mean to say when API 27 app is running on API 26 device, the v27 support libraries are causing the exception ? And when we lower the targetSDKVersion to 26, support library v26 are getting included ?

Comment: If you are referring to the IllegalState exception above then the reason for that is covered in the answers in the provided link. A v27 support library should not cause an exception on an API 26 device (unless used incorrectly or the library itself has a bug). The version of the support library used is set in the build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Android docs have mentioned behaviour changes when `targetSdkVersion` is changed.  For example, back in API 19 we were told that Android 4.4's WebView [operates in "quirks mode" in apps that target API level 18 and lower](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4), as well as `AlarmManager` and `ContentResolver` keeping some of their old behaviour for such apps.  We were also told about a [small change to WifiConfiguration in Android 6](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes) that checks if `targetSdkVersion` is 20 or lower, and a [temporary reprieve on linking to non-NDK platform libraries in Android 7](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes) if `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or lower.  More dramatic was the bunch of [Android 8 behaviour changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes), some of which check for `targetSdkVersion` being 26 or above before giving you the new behaviour.  Basically they want you to read the "Behaviour Changes" sections of every new API that comes out.

Comment: But then how exactly is the device OS version affecting these behaviors ? In my case the device is on 26.0.0. And the changes added a particular API for targetSdkVersion 27 in the Android code base should not be affect the API in v26 ?Unless the device is upgraded to v27, how is it going to be aware of the changes added in v27 ?

Comment: Sounds like a possible bug in API 26 to me.  On an API 26 device, it may make a difference if target is 25 versus 26, but it SHOULDN'T make a difference if target is 27 versus 26.  If it does, it's plausible that some API 27 code was accidentally released early and you've managed to activate it.  If you can simulate an API 25 device I'd try to reproduce on that first to verify that the problem is specific to an API 26 device.  You could then detect the API at runtime and make it not run the affected code on 26, or just re-code that whole section to avoid using the affected part of the API.