# my app does not have any errors when it builds, however, it stops working when I run it on my phone

Tags: java, android, logcat

my app does not have any errors when it builds, however, it stops working when I run it on my phone, and when I open the app it stopped working and then I decided to run it in the debug and see the errors that have in it through logcat

My build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    configurations.all {exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'}
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "tdl.com.dindim"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.adefruandta.spinningwheel:spinningwheel:0.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    implementation 'org.immutables:gson:2.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'gun0912.ted:tedpermission:2.1.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Logcat  error (I just took the words that were in red)

```
2019-07-19 03:33:43.960 7572-7572/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: binding to the service failed
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
2019-07-19 04:23:16.863 15686-15704/? E/DIAL:SsdpWriter: Error sending M-SEARCH request
    java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
        at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:686)
        at com.google.android.music.dial.SsdpWriter.sendSearch(SsdpWriter.java:67)
        at com.google.android.music.dial.SsdpScanner.run(SsdpScanner.java:45)
        at com.google.android.music.utils.async.TraceableRunnable.runLogged(TraceableRunnable.java:21)
        at com.google.android.music.utils.async.LoggedRunnable.run(LoggedRunnable.java:30)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at com.google.android.music.utils.LoggableHandler.dispatchMessage(LoggableHandler.java:74)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

Debug error (I just took the words that were in red)

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: tdl.com.dindim, PID: 11596
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tdl.com.dindim/com.gun0912.tedpermission.TedPermissionActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen opaque activities can request orientation
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2830)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2909)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1606)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6592)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen opaque activities can request orientation
        at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:991)
        at android.support.v4.app.SupportActivity.onCreate(ComponentActivity.java:75)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:335)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:85)
        at com.gun0912.tedpermission.TedPermissionActivity.onCreate(TedPermissionActivity.java:69)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1235)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2783)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2909) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1606) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6592) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769) 
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tdl.com.dindim/com.gun0912.tedpermission.TedPermissionActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen opaque activities can request orientation
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2830)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2909)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1606)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6592)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen opaque activities can request orientation
        at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:991)
        at android.support.v4.app.SupportActivity.onCreate(ComponentActivity.java:75)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:335)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:85)
        at com.gun0912.tedpermission.TedPermissionActivity.onCreate(TedPermissionActivity.java:69)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1235)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2783)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2909) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1606) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6592) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769) 


E/FirebaseCrash: Unable to parse Json response string to get message: No value for crashes
```

My MainActivity

```
package tdl.com.dindim.activities;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

import java.util.List;

import tdl.com.dindim.R;
import tdl.com.dindim.managers.SpinManager;
import tdl.com.dindim.managers.WithdrawManager;
import tdl.com.dindim.models.Score;
import tdl.com.dindim.models.Withdraw;
import tdl.com.dindim.utils.ApplicationMode;
import tdl.com.dindim.utils.ConnectionChecker;
import tdl.com.dindim.utils.SharedPreferenceValue;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements WithdrawManager.WithdrawFeedbackListener {

    private TextView tvTotalEarn, tvLastWithdraw;
    private AdView adView, adView2, adView3;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    private WithdrawManager withdrawManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {
        tvTotalEarn = findViewById(R.id.tvTotalEarn);
        tvLastWithdraw = findViewById(R.id.tvLastWithdraw);
        adView = findViewById(R.id.adViewD);
        adView2 = findViewById(R.id.adView2D);
        adView3 = findViewById(R.id.adView3D);
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.dashboard_interstitial_ads));
        loadAds();
        showInterstitialAdds();
        if (ConnectionChecker.isOnline(MainActivity.this)) {
            new SpinManager(MainActivity.this, false, new SpinManager.SpinFeedbackListener() {
                @Override
                public void pointSaveSuccess() {

                }

                @Override
                public void pointSaveFailed() {

                }

                @Override
                public void noLastPointFound() {
                    tvTotalEarn.setText("My Total Earn Points: 0");
                }

                @Override
                public void userLastScore(Score score) {
                    tvTotalEarn.setText("My Total Earn Points: " + score.getPoints());

                }

                @Override
                public void updateScoreSuccess() {

                }

                @Override
                public void updateScoreFailed() {

                }

                @Override
                public void noScoreForTodayUpdateScoreOnly(Score score) {
                    tvTotalEarn.setText("My Total Earn Points: " + score.getPoints());

                }
            }).getUserLastScore(SharedPreferenceValue.getLoggedinUser(MainActivity.this));
            withdrawManager = new WithdrawManager(MainActivity.this, false, this);
            withdrawManager.getUserLastWithdraw(SharedPreferenceValue.getLoggedinUser(MainActivity.this));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No internet . try to connect with internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void loadAds() {
//        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-4836336224499913/6703144349"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
        //mAdViewTop.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-4836336224499913/6703144349");
        if (ApplicationMode.devMode) {
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice("35E1AEC74E43C6B3529C4F77AC4CB10F")
                    .build();
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        } else {
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    //.addTestDevice("35E1AEC74E43C6B3529C4F77AC4CB10F")
                    .build();
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
        if (ApplicationMode.devMode) {
            AdRequest adRequest2 = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice("35E1AEC74E43C6B3529C4F77AC4CB10F")
                    .build();
            adView2.loadAd(adRequest2);
        } else {
            AdRequest adRequest2 = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    //.addTestDevice("35E1AEC74E43C6B3529C4F77AC4CB10F")
                    .build();
            adView2.loadAd(adRequest2);
        }
        if (ApplicationMode.devMode) {
            AdRequest adRequest3 = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice("35E1AEC74E43C6B3529C4F77AC4CB10F")
                    .build();
            adView3.loadAd(adRequest3);
        } else {
            AdRequest adRequest3 = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    //.addTestDevice("35E1AEC74E43C6B3529C4F77AC4CB10F")
                    .build();
            adView3.loadAd(adRequest3);
        }
    }

    private void showInterstitialAdds() {
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Load the next interstitial.
                //mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            }

        });
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                showAdsFinal();
            }
        }, 5000);
    }

    void showAdsFinal() {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void withdrawSaveSuccess() {

    }

    @Override
    public void withdrawSaveFailed() {

    }

    @Override
    public void noLastWithdrawFound() {
        tvLastWithdraw.setText("My Last Withdraw: 0");
    }

    @Override
    public void userLastWithdraw(Withdraw withdraw) {
        tvLastWithdraw.setText("My Last Withdraw: " + withdraw.getWithdrawPoints());


    }

    @Override
    public void withDrawRequests(List<Withdraw> withdrawList) {

    }

    @Override
    public void noRequestsAvailable() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen opaque activities can request orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48072438/java-lang-illegalstateexception-only-fullscreen-opaque-activities-can-request-o)

Comment: Are you trying to set any activity's as portrait/landscape?

Comment: post code of mainactivity

Comment: problem is in `TedPermissionActivity` which you did not show

Comment: I do not have an activity called "TedPermissions Activity"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. are u using Android 8.0?
2. Try delete android：screenOrientation='portrait' in manifest
3. In style, `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>` set True to false
4. If not work, test with another phone

Comment: What do you mean, style? Where is this style? but that did not resolve to delete the "android: screenOrientation = 'portrait'" in manifest gave a PTT2 error

Comment: In styles.xml: `<style name="AppTranslateTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/animation_translucent_translate</item>
</style>`

Comment: Just edit your answer to provide additional information, don't provide them in comments. @Lazyboy

Comment: I did that you said to delete the Try delete android: screenOrientation = 'portrait' in manifest so step 3 did different, what I did was in each of my activity and put
`// android The fix bug orientation
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }`

 in java activity