# How to restrict screen orientation to portrait in Android SDK 27

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, screen-orientation

I have tried

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

and

```
setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

but it is crashing the app, Is there any alternative method for this to work in Android 8.0.0+?

Logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: in.ajtech.finX, PID: 15077
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.ajtech.finX/in.ajtech.finX.CalendarActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen activities can request orientation
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen activities can request orientation
      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1950)
      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1888)
      at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.setRequestedOrientation(IActivityManager.java:5675)
      at android.app.Activity.setRequestedOrientation(Activity.java:5739)
      at in.ajtech.finX.CalendarActivity.onCreate(CalendarActivity.java:55)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Comment: `but it is crashing the app,` share logcat

Comment: refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980697/lock-screen-orientation-when-targeting-android-api-27-with-a-non-opaque-activity

Comment: post your `styles.xml`

Comment: @MohammadAli i have tried, but the accepted answer there says to set screenorientation as "unspecified". but with that i cant set orientation to portrait.

Comment: `Only fullscreen activities can request orientation at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity` - do you have the theme which is not full-screen?

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46992843/interstitial-admob-ads-illegalstateexception-only-fullscreen-activities-can-r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### BUG

Read [**`Only fullscreen activities can request orientation`**](https://github.com/Instabug/android-sample/issues/68)

> Only fullscreen activities can request orientation at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity

You should use [**`AppCompatActivity`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) instead of **`Activity`**.

let your activity extend **`AppCompatActivity`**.

**JAVA**

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  // ...
}
```

**Kotlin**

```
class  YourActivity : AppCompatActivity()
```

**`FYI`**

> Beginning with Android 3.0 (API level 11), all activities that use the
>   default theme have an ActionBar as an app bar. However, app bar
>   features have gradually been added to the native ActionBar over
>   various Android releases. As a result, the native ActionBar behaves
>   differently depending on what version of the Android system a device
>   may be using. By contrast, the most recent features are added to the
>   support library's version of Toolbar, and they are available on any
>   device that can use the support library.

From [**`Setting Up the App Bar`**](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html).

**`DEMO`**

Set your style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

</style>
```

Comment: This is not a real solution. What if I want to have the ActionBar?  Google should just fix this crash that they have newly introduced.

Answer (score 1):

It's android sdk(27) issue , you can't use `portrait` with `Translucent` so reduce your target sdk to `26` or remove `Translucent` theme or remove `portrait` mode.

Answer (score 1):

In `AndroidManifest.xml` make the following changes:

1. For opaque activities, i.e. full-screen, set:

   ```xml
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
   ```

   Note that the theme should be NOT Translucent.
2. For transclusent activities, i.e. pop-up dialogs etc, set:

   ```xml
   android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
   ```

   Note that screenOrientation is not specified here. You can use Translucent themes.

This works without downgrading SDK version.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property from you manifest file, inside each activity, add  `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`

Comment: it is working successfull before sdk 26.but in >=26 it is crashing

Answer (score 0):

Repacing `extents Activity` to `AppCompatActivity` fixed the issue. Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, when I tried to open activity as dialog inside another activity.
then I removed `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` from dialog activity deceleration in my Manifest, and problem solved!
this is because the parent activity should be responsible for the orientation.